# Database query for count

Tags: sql, group-by

I have one table with

```
ID  |   NAME    |   DEPT
1   |   A       |   D-1
2   |   B       |   D-1
3   |   C       |   D-2
4   |   D       |   D-3
5   |   E       |   D-1
6   |   F       |   D-3
7   |   G       |   D-4
```

Now I want to fetch result like

```
DEPT    |   COUNT(DEPT)
D-1     |   3
OTHERS  |   4
```

Can any one help me to write this query?

Comment: We don't write code for you here. What have you attempted?

Comment: Aoplogies for the down/close voters, the SQL tag is particularly nasty at the moment :S

Comment: Which DBMS is this for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `CASE` to group the data by `D-1` and `Others`:

```
select 
  case when dept = 'D-1' then 'D-1' else 'Others' end as Dept,
  count(*) as Total
from yt
group by case when dept = 'D-1' then 'D-1' else 'Others' end;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1258e/2)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the maximum occurred Dept with count and other dept with the sum of rest dept occurrence.

well you can do like below -

```
Select dept, count(*) cnt  
  from Table_name
 group by dept
having count(*) = ( select max(count(*)) from table_name group by dept)
union
select 'Other' dept, count(*) cnt 
  from table_name 
 where dept not in ( select dept 
                       from table_name 
                      group by dept 
                     having count(*) = ( select max(count(*)) 
                                           from table_name 
                                          group by dept
                                        )
                   )
```

I hope this is what you are looking for..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     DEPT,
     COUNT (DEPT)AS [COUNT(DEPT)]
FROM(SELECT 
          (CASE DEPT WHEN 'D-1' THEN 'D-1' ELSE 'OTHERS' END) AS DEPT FROM test1) AS tbl
GROUP BY DEPT
```

Please try above sql query.